# Pages not found error if debug is false

Tags: cakephp-3.0

On my developement server `/pages/help` renders just fine. But on the production it renders a not found page.

All the files are the same, and everything else works.

**Update:** The only difference is on production debug is false and on developement debug is true. I can reproducate the problem by changing debug value.

Here is the stack trace

```
2015-07-08 10:36:44 Error: [Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException] Not Found
Request URL: /pages/help
Stack Trace:
#0 /home/reseller10/domains/1108.cc/private_html/sanga/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/View/View.php(833): include()
#1 /home/reseller10/domains/1108.cc/private_html/sanga/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/View/View.php(793): Cake\View\View->_evaluate('/home/reseller1...', Array)
#2 /home/reseller10/domains/1108.cc/private_html/sanga/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/View/View.php(464): Cake\View\View->_render('/home/reseller1...')
#3 /home/reseller10/domains/1108.cc/private_html/sanga/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/Controller.php(582): Cake\View\View->render('help', NULL)
#4 /home/reseller10/domains/1108.cc/private_html/sanga/src/Controller/PagesController.php(63): Cake\Controller\Controller->render('help')
#5 [internal function]: App\Controller\PagesController->display('help')
#6 /home/reseller10/domains/1108.cc/private_html/sanga/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Controller/Controller.php(411): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#7 /home/reseller10/domains/1108.cc/private_html/sanga/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Dispatcher.php(114): Cake\Controller\Controller->invokeAction()
#8 /home/reseller10/domains/1108.cc/private_html/sanga/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Routing/Dispatcher.php(87): Cake\Routing\Dispatcher->_invoke(Object(App\Controller\PagesController))
#9 /home/reseller10/domains/1108.cc/private_html/sanga/webroot/index.php(37): Cake\Routing\Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(Cake\Network\Request), Object(Cake\Network\Response))
#10 {main}
```

Comment: That's not really a suitable question for SO, I mean, what are people supposed to do now other than shooting in the dark? Maybe it's a permission issue, maybe it's a naming issue, maybe...

Comment: If I would know more, I would give more information. :) The permissions are ok, naming is ok. Anyway thanks for the shoots.

Comment: I managed to reproducate the problem on my developement server. If I set debug to false I have the same error.

Comment: it seems to be a bug, I will create an issue on github

Comment: Are you sure that you have't just used the `home.ctp` file as a template for your other pages, and forgot to remove [**https://github.com/cakephp/.../home.ctp#L23-L25](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/3.0.3/src/Template/Pages/home.ctp#L23-L25)** ?

Comment: @ndm Thanks. That's it, you are right. Why is it there at all?

Comment: Because the page reveals system information that should not be made public.

Comment: To add to @ndm, _'A Not Found error page is expected with debug false and accessing the default homepage due to [this code](https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/3.0.3/src/Template/Pages/home.ctp#L23-L25). It's done because people often forget to change/remove the default homepage exposing potentially sensitive info in live app.'_, [discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/cakephp/app/issues/43#issuecomment-38468031)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spend 1 hour searching the error. First thought its a permissions problem on logs. But it's much easier.

Remove

```
if (!Configure::read('debug')):
    throw new NotFoundException();
endif;
```

From `Template/Layout/default.ctp`

Comment: Removed from src/Template/Layout/default.ctp

Comment: Does anyone have an idea what it the reason for this stupid 3 lines?

Comment: You should not use the contained layouts for a productive service. They're just an example. But it seems many people use them, me included. Additionally, the base ctp. file is very simplistic but easy-to-understand, it uses no layout.